# OCaml: Set modules

Tags: module, set, ocaml

I want to use OCaml to generates sets of data and make comparisons between them. I have seen the documentation for Module types like `Set.OrderType`, `Set.Make`, etc, but I can't figure out how to initialize a set or otherwise use them.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Sets are defined using a functorial interface. For any given type, you have to create a `Set` module for that type using the `Set.Make` functor. An unfortunate oversight of the standard libraries is that they don't define `Set` instances for the built-in types. In most simple cases, it's sufficient to use `Pervasives.compare`. Here's a definition that works for `int`:

```
module IntSet = Set.Make( 
  struct
    let compare = Pervasives.compare
    type t = int
  end )
```

The module `IntSet` will implement the `Set.S` interface. Now you can operate on sets using the `IntSet` module:

```
let s = IntSet.empty ;;
let t = IntSet.add 1 s ;;
let u = IntSet.add 2 s ;;
let tu = IntSet.union t u ;;
```

Note that you don't have to explicitly define the input structure for `Set.Make` as an `OrderedType`; type inference will do the work for you. Alternatively, you could use the following definition:

```
module IntOrder : Set.OrderedType = struct
  type t = int
  let compare = Pervasives.compare
end

module IntSet = Set.Make( IntOrder )
```

This has the advantage that you can re-use the same module to instantiate a `Map`:

```
module IntMap = Map.Make( IntOrder )
```

You lose some genericity in using functors, because the type of the elements is fixed. For example, you won't be able to define a function that takes a `Set` of some arbitrary type and performs some operation on it. (Luckily, the `Set` module itself declares many useful operations on `Set`s.)

Comment: "you won't be able to define a function that takes a Set of some arbitrary type" you could, however, accomplish the same thing by defining the function inside a functor which takes your specific Set module as a parameter. but to use it of course the programmer would have to make yet another module with this functor, so it is less convenient

Comment: Right. It's functors all the way down.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to Chris's answer, it may be useful to say that some standard library modules already adhere to the `OrderedType` signature. For example, you can simply do:

```
module StringSet = Set.Make(String) ;;       (* sets of strings *)
module Int64Set = Set.Make(Int64) ;;         (* sets of int64s *)
module StringSetSet = Set.Make(StringSet) ;; (* sets of sets of strings *)
```

And so on.

Here's a simple usage example for `StringSet`; remember that sets are functional data structures, so adding a new element to a set returns a new set:

```
let set = List.fold_right StringSet.add ["foo";"bar";"baz"] StringSet.empty ;;
StringSet.mem "bar" set ;; (* returns true *)
StringSet.mem "zzz" set ;; (* returns false *)
```