# How do I use sets in OCaml?

Tags: module, ocaml

I want to write a function that, given a non-negative integer n, returns the power set of {1,...,n}. So I want to use the Set.S module as found [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Set.S.html). But I can't seem to import it. When I run the following code:

```
open Set.S

let rec power_set n =
  if n = 0 then add empty empty else union (iter (add n s) power_set (n-1)) (power_set (n-1));;

let print_set s = SS.iter print_endline s;;

print_set (power_set 2)
```

I get the error:

```
File "countTopologies.ml", line 1, characters 5-10:
Error: Unbound module Set.S
```

Maybe I just don't have the Set.S module installed on my computer? (I've only done the bare bones needed to install OCaml). If this is the case, how would I get it?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452218/ocaml-set-modules

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Set.S` is a *module type*, not a module. You can open only modules. In fact, the module `Set` contains three elements:

- the module type `OrderedType` that denotes the type of modules that implement ordered types;
- the module type `S` that denotes the type of modules that implement `Set` data structures;
- the functor `Make` that takes a module of type `OrderedType` and returns a module of type `S`.

To get a set module you need to create it using the `Set.Make` functor. The functor has one parameter - the module for the set elements. In modern OCaml (4.08+) you can create a set module for integers as easy as,

```
module Ints = Set.Make(Int)
```

and then you can use like this,

```
let numbers = Ints.of_list [1;2;3]
assert (Ints.mem 2 numbers)
```

For older versions of OCaml, which doesn't provide the `Int` module, or for non-standard (custom) types, you need to define your own module that implements the `OrderedType` interface, e.g.,

```
 module Int = struct 
   type t = int 
   (* use Pervasives compare *)
   let compare = compare
 end

 module Ints = Set.Make(Int)
```

You can also use non-standard libraries, like Janestreet's Core library, which provide sets out of box. The Core library has an `Int` module that is already charged with sets, maps, hashtables, so it can be accessed without any functors:

```
open Core.Std

let nil = Int.Set.empty
```

Or, in the modern (2018-2019) version of Janestreet Core or Base libraries, you can use polymorphic sets/maps, which require you to specify the module for keys only when a new set or map is created, e.g., like this

```
open Base (* or Core, or Core_kernel *)

let nil = Set.empty (module Int)
let one = Set.add nil 1
let two = Set.singleton (module Int) 2
```

Comment: I don't suppose there's any nice way of initializing a set like you can in say Java or Haskell. "many = {3,4,5}" or something like that.

Comment: So there is, via Seqs. Here's something that works:       `let many = StrSet.add_seq (List.to_seq ["a";"b";"c"]) StrSet.empty`

Comment: @N.S. there is the `of_list` function both in the standard library and in the core libraries, e.g., `StrSet.of_list ["a"; "b"; "c"]`

Answer (score 3):

You have to `Make` a set module from the Set functor.

```
module SI = Set.Make(struct type t = int let compare = compare end)
```

Then you can have a set of ints:

```
# let myset = SI.add 3 SI.empty;;
val myset : SI.t = <abstr>
# SI.elements myset;;
- : SI.elt list = [3]
```